# Jquery - .click() function dont work on appended divs

Tags: jquery, click

I have a function in javascript

```
function whatClassNorH(thatDiv,prop){
    if(prop==='numer'){
        for(var i=0; i<tab.length;i++){
            if($(thatDiv).hasClass('numer_'+i))return i;
        }
    }
    if(prop==='hide_id'){
        for(var i=0; i<=maxID;i++){
            if($(thatDiv).hasClass('hide_id_'+i))return i;
        }
    }
}
function drawZadania(){
    $('.content').html('');
    for(var i=0; i<tab.length;i++){
        if(tab[i][1]===0 || tab[i][1]==='0'){
            $('.content').append('<div class="zadanie_line numer_' + i + ' hide_id_' + tab[i][0] + '"></div>');

            $('.content .zadanie_line.numer_'+i).append('<div class="single_property priorytet numer_' + i + ' hide_id_' + tab[i][0] + '">Priorytet</div>');
            $('.content .zadanie_line.numer_'+i).append('<div class="single_property dziedzina numer_' + i + ' hide_id_' + tab[i][0] + '">Dziedzina</div>');
            $('.content .zadanie_line.numer_'+i).append('<div class="single_property tytul numer_' + i + ' hide_id_' + tab[i][0] + '">Tytul</div>');
            $('.content .zadanie_line.numer_'+i).append('<div class="single_property data numer_' + i + ' hide_id_' + tab[i][0] + '">Data</div>');
            $('.content .zadanie_line.numer_'+i).append('<div class="single_property opis numer_' + i + ' hide_id_' + tab[i][0] + '">Opis</div>');

            $('.single_property.priorytet.numer_' + i + '.hide_id_' + tab[i][0]).html(tab[i][2]);
            $('.single_property.dziedzina.numer_' + i + '.hide_id_' + tab[i][0]).html(tab[i][3]);
            $('.single_property.tytul.numer_' + i + '.hide_id_' + tab[i][0]).html(tab[i][4]);
            $('.single_property.data.numer_' + i + '.hide_id_' + tab[i][0]).html($.date(tab[i][5]));
            $('.single_property.opis.numer_' + i + '.hide_id_' + tab[i][0]).html(tab[i][6]);
        }

    }
}

$('#btn_sortuj').click(function(){
    $('.second_menu').append('<div id="btn_sort_priorytet">Sortuj Według Priorytetu</div>');
    $('.second_menu').append('<div id="btn_sort_dziedzina">Sortuj Według Dziedziny</div>');
    $('.second_menu').append('<div id="btn_sort_data">Sortuj Według Daty</div>');
});

$('#btn_sort_priorytet').click(function(){
    sortPriorytet();
    drawZadania();
});       
$('#btn_zobacz').click(function(){
    sortPriorytet();
    drawZadania();
}); 
$('.zadanie_line').click(function(){
    console.log('numer: '+ whatClassNorH(this,'numer'));
    console.log('hideId: '+ whatClassNorH(this,'hide_id'));
});

drawZadania();
checkPage();
```

How it works:
When the page start, and later on click on #btn_zobacz, the click event properly triggers, because #btn_zobacz in in html of page. Later, when I click #btn_sortuj - it appends the another three divs which work as buttons. When I click on them, nothing happens.

Also, when the page load for first time, I use drawZadania() function, and when I click on the .zadanie_line element - it properly console.log number of .number and .hiddenId. But when I draw them again with #btn_zobacz, the click('.zadania_line') do not trigger.

My problem is, that the click function simply do not respond on all click on divs. What should I do?

Comment: `on` / `live` functions

Comment: Your code shows an great amount of duplication. That's a bad sign. You should try to abstract and shorten it, at least by 50%. Please don't use copy and paste as a programming tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delegation with .on():

```
$('.content').on('click','.zadanie_line',function(){
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use event delegation for this. The reason is because your `btn_sort_priorytet`, `zadanie_line` are created dynamically but the event handlers are bound much earlier than the creation of the element. So your code must look like this :

```
$('.second_menu').on("click", '#btn_sort_priorytet', function () {
    sortPriorytet();
    drawZadania();
});

$(document).on("click", '#btn_zobacz", function () { //or closest static parent (an element which exists all the time
    sortPriorytet();
    drawZadania();
});
$(".content").on("click", '.zadanie_line', function () {
    console.log('numer: ' + whatClassNorH(this, 'numer'));
    console.log('hideId: ' + whatClassNorH(this, 'hide_id'));
});
```

If you're using an older version of jQuery, say v1.7, you could also use `live()`. Its not there in the latest versions of jQuery so beware of its use. Also, compared to `on`, performance of `live` is poor.

```
$('#btn_sort_priorytet').live("click", function () {
    sortPriorytet();
    drawZadania();
});
$('#btn_zobacz').live("click", function () {
    sortPriorytet();
    drawZadania();
});
$('.zadanie_line').live("click", function () {
    console.log('numer: ' + whatClassNorH(this, 'numer'));
    console.log('hideId: ' + whatClassNorH(this, 'hide_id'));
});
```

Docs for `on` : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Docs for `live` : http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('.content').on('click', '.zadanie_line', function(){
    console.log('numer: '+ whatClassNorH(this,'numer'));
    console.log('hideId: '+ whatClassNorH(this,'hide_id'));
});
```

The handler will then be attached to all the existing `.zadanie_line` elements and all those created in future.